# How to get theatre cafe to appear in Google searches for "cafe"?

Tags: seo, google-search

This is a question about a businesses with two categories: Performing arts theatre (primary category) + cafe (secondary). 
The arts theatre performs well in theatre-related searches. 
It has a cafe which is featured on the website, but "nearby" searches on Google for "cafe in town-name" don't even list it, and text search lists it below smaller but more single-minded cafes. 
I thought about creating a new Google Business as the cafe at the same location, but then reviews would get split between the two.
So how can I tell Google to return it in searches for cafes?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no way to have one business listed in two categories (theatre and cafe). Suggest you to submit two listings instead.

Worry not about reviews being split because it's actually better if it's split because those who search for your cafe would prefer to read reviews about your cafe instead of your theatre.

Comment: I totally agree! Verify each Google My Business page. If you have a website, you can create a page or a subdomain for the cafe-related stuff. It would be better to organize if the two different categories are split.

Comment: Thanks, makes good sense. Is there any real advantage in having a subdomain as opposed to path/pages?

Answer (score 0):

- You can specify of connection the cafe to theater in the structure of the web page. **[For example](https://docs.google.com/document/d/19cezcbgEL7pspHC04X7s28RG6v0gwmyFVKtDmymXcMg/)**.
  Its does not necessarily comply with the values of the elements H (h1-h2-h3...). You can apply the elements h2-h3..., for example, for current theater events, his repertoire and so on, in order of priority. If the main event of the theater is an upcoming performance, then this should take precedence over the markup of the theater cafe. Markup the name of the cafe with a lower value of element H will show that the cafe is part of the theater, in the structure of the web page.
- Also, you can apply the markup to structured data to Theater = **[TheaterGroup](http://schema.org/TheaterGroup)** and to Cafe **[CafeOrCoffeeShop](http://schema.org/CafeOrCoffeeShop)**. **[For example](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cQAmW3NVE2RPAwNImuGRsdBuVrOnbTr-HzwIZizfVuk/)**.

I hope this helps you.